# Canonical Post #2 is up!

Tags: discussion, canonical-posts

I'm pleased to announce that our second Canonical Post is up, thanks to StoneyB!  A quick refresher on Canonical Posts, in case you've forgotten:

> The idea behind Canonical Posts is to take a subject which is often encountered by English Language Learners and create a post which thoroughly explains that topic. The goal is for these posts to be as useful and easy-to-understand as possible, so feedback is greatly appreciated, especially concerning areas which we could improve. Please do leave comments on the posts with any thoughts or questions you may have.

So please, do go check out the post! It's pretty clear that Stoney put a *lot* of work into this, so I hope everyone will read and enjoy (and share it with others!)

[Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/289)

You can view a list of all Canonical Posts by clicking the *canonical-post* tag on the question.

---

At the moment we don't have any other Canonical Posts in the pipeline, but we'd really like to continue on with these. If anyone has any suggestions for a topic they'd like to see a Canonical Post on, or would like to volunteer to write one, please chime in here! Posts of any length on any relevant topic are welcome, and I'd love to discuss this further with anyone who's interested!

Comment: We do seem to have a lot of questions relating to the status of phrases as complements or adjuncts, but I suspect many of our users are unfamiliar with these terms or what their significance might be.  I'm not sure whether this would be an appropriate topic for a canonical post, though.

Comment: @snailboat If you see a pattern in questions asking about it then I'd say it's definitely an appropriate topic, and if you're interested in writing it then I even more heartily endorse it :)

Comment: @snailboat Go for it - there's a crying need. ... I'm considering one on conditionals, which are ludicrously misrepresented by the standard 0th, 1st, 2nd &c framework it seems half our visitors are taught.

Comment: A suggestion for the next post -- The articles (a, the).

Comment: There's very little one can do for articles except go over the pronunciation and then catalog the idioms. And make a point that article rules are variable, usually optional, and rarely obligatory. Articles are just gears in the machinery, and they have a lot of functions; one might as well try to write a canonical article on the Philips screwdriver.